# Get WCF server raw response in svcutil generated proxy class

Tags: response, svcutil.exe, proxy-classes

Is it possible to prevent deserialization, or to have access to Operation result class of webmethod in generated proxy class without writing your own proxy class?
Thanks.

Comment: I mean maybe there some attributes that can prevent deserialization and get raw response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems using generated class that's impossible, until you write your own class and prevent data deserialization.